# Failure to install Siverlight

Tags: windows-xp, installation, silverlight

I tried to install [Silverlight from the Microsoft site](http://www.silverlight.net/). The download is fine. I got Silverlight.exe (4.7MB).

However, when I try and run it, I get the message saying "file is corrupt" during the process of extracting Silverlight.7z to my c:\833xxx (looks like a temp folder).

I tried yesterday and rebooted my machine twice. I tried it again today with the same problem.

Not sure if it is related to an access permission issue or not (I just got this new PC).

My PC is Windows XP Professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a corrupt installer file cached in your browser or proxy somewhere.  Delete your temp files and browser's cached files and try the download again.

Comment: Another solution is also to download it using another browser, where it isn't already cached. If something fails in Chrome, I tend to jump to Firefox or IE to quickly get around it.

Comment: Good point!

Comment: I tried Firefox, Chrome and IE. All have the same issue.

Comment: By the way, I don't have any problems to install other applications from MSDN and Open source projects.

Comment: Now I tried IE to the link (Silverlight download) and clicked on Run directly when I saw prompt. This time it works fine. I got it installed. By the way, Firefox and Chrome are still not working if I send the exe file. Really strange.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft doesn't distribute its software in .7z format, so I believe you got the wrong file.
The correct download location is [here](http://www.silverlight.net/).

Comment: Not true.  The official Silverlight.exe self-extracting installer includes a file named silverlight.7z One of the major goals is to keep the redistributable installer small and 7z format is definitely a way to do that.

Comment: However, I was right in that this was a bad download.:-)